# Parsing floats from a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, regex

I'd like parse the float numbers of an array how this:

`var array = "-51.2132,0.3100";`

I tried with `match(/\d+/g)` but I'd like to take float

Any idea about the `regex`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regex isn't required here. You can first split the coordinates by `,` to get the values, the use `ParseFloat` to cast them. Try this:

```
var loc = "-51.2132,0.3100".split(',');
var lat = parseFloat(loc[0]); // = -51.2132
var lon = parseFloat(loc[1]); // = 0.31
```

Comment: Hm, those might indeed be coordinates. Nice guess!

Comment: Thanks, now I know where spongebob lives https://www.google.nl/maps/place/51%C2%B012%2747.5%22S+0%C2%B018%2736.0%22E/@-51.213078,0.3104795,4z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x0:0x0 why do you think that it is a location? though, the code is good so +1 from me

Comment: @JPHellemons Just an assumption based on the -51.232 not being that far from the greenwich meridian :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var floats = array.split(',').map(function(e){return parseFloat(e)});
// result:
[-51.2132, 0.31]
```

What this line does: first, split the `array` on the comma character:

```
array.split(',') // ["-51.2132", "0.3100"]
```

Then, replace each `item` in that array with a `parseFloat(item)`:

```
["-51.2132", "0.3100"].map(function(e){ // For each item in the array
    return parseFloat(e); // Cast the current value to a float.
}); // [-51.2132, 0.31]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)
```

Try this.Grab the match.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/dZ1vT6/43

Answer (score -1):

Try this one:

```
var array = "-51.2132,0.3100";
var regex = /-?\d+\.?\d*/g;
var items = array.match(regex);
var numbers = items.map(function (item) {
    return parseFloat(item);
});
```

http://regexr.com/39o6i